# How to force the items of a window to be well-formed, like in Windows?

Tags: macos, filesystem, folders, ui

When I create a folder it will be placed in an irrelevant position to the existing items in that directory, making a mess, killing all aesthetics, whatsoever. How to make the elements to be listed in a grid or something, like for example in Windows? I want this option to be the default.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Perhaps `Finder menu > View > Show View Options > Sort by: > Snap to Grid` is what  you're looking for:
[image]
[image]

Comment: Where is the Menu? =)

Comment: Click on the Desktop so that Finder appears to the right of the Apple menu. You should see the menu items **File Edit View Go Window Help**.

Comment: Yeah, that's where I am at, but I cannot see the word "menu" anywhere. :/

Comment: I just augmented the answer with a nice graphic.

Comment: Ah "Finder menu", not go to Finder and then search for Menu...Dah, sorry IconDeamon, but my mind is melting [on this C++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41204050/error-no-matching-constructor-for-initialization-of-stdthread) question! Thank.